# Symfony get Asset Name in Assetic output

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

I generate my file with code like this:

```
{% block head_stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        filter='?uglifycss'
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/less/myfile.less'
    %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock head_stylesheets %}
```

It dumps a file named like this: `c543k540_myfile_1.css`

This file is composed of the asset name followed by the filename: `{assetName}_{filename}.css`

How can I customize the output in keeping the asset name in the output?

```
{% block head_stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        output="css/mynewfilename.{assetName}.css"     // <--- Here
        filter='?uglifycss'
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/less/myfile.less'
    %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock head_stylesheets %}
```

---

*Update to clarify*

I know that if I use the name option, in prod it will compile to `myouputname.css` but what I would like to have in debug/dev environment is following the bellow code something like `myfile_myouputname_1.css`

```
{% block head_stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets
        name="myouputname"     // <--- Here
        filter='?uglifycss'
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/less/myfile.less'
    %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock head_stylesheets %}
```

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Assuming you have look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files What is the generated output using the second code below?

Comment: The generated output is "mynewfilename.{assetName}.css"

Comment: what exactly is your desired filename to get in the output? Just *c543k540.css* ? In `dev` environement the command dumps the chunks for each asset and also the combined file. You should find two files *c543k540_myfile_1.css* and *c543k540.css*. If you dump the assets for `prod` environment with `bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` it should create only the main file  *c543k540.css`. Remember to clear the cache before dumping in prod.

Comment: So to clarify, if your asset contains `name="foo"`, and `output="mynewfilename.{assetName}.css"`, you expect a file named `mynewfilename.foo.css`?

Comment: output is what I've tried, but with no success, finally I just want to have {filename}_{name}.css in debug env instead of {name}_{filename}.css, actually I'm looking into this Assetic file https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Extension/Twig/AsseticNode.php#L93

Comment: I advise you to use webpack. It will be much easier to do this type of thing https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend.html

Comment: @LeMenachFlorian Yes thanks for comment, It's an old question... I'm agree with you in your days... It's what I use now.

Comment: Excuse me, I did not pay attention to the date :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Assetic to manage web assets in Symfony applications is no longer recommended. Instead, use Webpack Encore.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/assetic/index.html#dumping-asset-files

Page-Specific JavaScript or CSS (Multiple Entries) is described here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#multiple-javascript-entries

```
// webpack.config.js
Encore
    // ... general CSS file here...
    .addStyleEntry('some_page', './assets/css/assetName.css')
;
```

Using addStyleEntry() is supported, but not recommended. A better option is to follow the pattern above: use addEntry() to point to a JavaScript file, then require the CSS needed from inside of that.